# Migrate Linux server to Windows

Tags: linux, windows

apologies for vague description but essentially I have a Linux box (Ubuntu) which has three drives. The first drive is formatted with a Linux format (I'm not sure which one but probably irrelevant) and the second and third drives are NTFS as they have been shares on a windows network.

Can I just reformat the first drive to NTFS and install windows? Would I expect windows to see drives 2 and 3 as they are already NTFS drives?

Thanks

Comment: can I ask why the downvote .. man I really wish downvoters would comment when doing it .. how is the rest of the world supposed to figure out how to improve contributions to SO

Comment: Are you sure that 2nd and 3rd are really NTFS ? "They have shares on a windows network" probably mean that there is samba installed, they may be e.g. Linux ext3 formatted. Samba provides CIFS protocol for Windows clients, the underlying file system on the Linux system need not be NTFS, in fact, it seems unlikely.

Comment: No they are NTFS .. they were created using GParted at setup a couple of years back .. as I didn't know what the server OS would end up being I formatted them as NTFS in the hope that they could be used on Windows (I also didn't know about Samba at that time and thought I had to format them as NTFS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup/Image your system before doing any changes, if the system is critical.

Yes, begin Windows installation process. There will be a point in the installation where you will be asked to select the drive/partition on which Windows should be installed. Your first drive will be listed. You can wipe it off and choose the entire drive for Windows. Default NTFS will be created for you.

If you have trouble, create gparted live CD and boot system with it. It will allow you to wipe off the first drive. Then install Windows on that drive.

Yes, Windows will see drive 2 and 3.

Also, you will get some nice help on https://serverfault.com/ if there are complications with disk setup (RAID/LVM etc.).

Comment: Thank you .. I have imaged the Linux drive and there is a back up of the NTFS drive (the third drive is purely a mirror of 2 which is up to date). No raid. Thanks very much for your help. Will mark this an the answer when able.

Comment: Very cool. You have already done a great job with keeping an image and backup.